# Need a blood-pressure measuring module recommendation for arduino

Tags: arduino

I need to record blood pressure with a [blood pressure cuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphygmomanometer) interfaced to an [Arduino uno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) module so the data can be logged. I searched the web for a such a device, but could not found anything useful.

Which modules should I look for?

Comment: Are you looking to build a blood pressure monitor, or are you hoping for something pre-made?

Comment: Yes arduino essential.I am working on arduino uno @K7AA7

Comment: Not exactly i need to store blood pressure data on a server and monitor the results on a graph lively.So i need the data from the module but i don't need an external monitor i just need to store it.@Alphy31

Comment: So you just want an input device you can write numbers to by hand?

Comment: No i am measuring my blood pressure and the results are needed to be parsed and stored in database lively @Alphy13.And i need an Arduino module to measure it.My question is which modules should i look for.For example i found an air pressure measurement module but i need to measure blood pressure.

Comment: Please provide much more info in your original post. Do you know how to wire electronics? Are you wanting plug and play? Can you build it yourself? Do you already have a device that takes blood pressure? Are you looking for a pressure sensor? An air pump? Are you looking a keyboard to input "120/60"?

Comment: I know how to build a circuit and wire electronics i just built a body heat sensor.I need a pressure sensor and probably an air pump which pressure sensor should i look for and once again i don't need manuel inputs. @Alphy13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I hear you ask for a module, I think of an Arduino "Shield" but you dont need one of these. You can connect what you need directly to the board, but it will be easier if you use a [breadboard](https://smile.amazon.com/4Pcs-MCIGICM-Point-Solderless-Breadboard/dp/B08115P2T4).

There is a really good paper [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~neil/teaching/lectures/med_elec/notes8.pdf) that describes the measurement process and even shows the low-pass amplifier they used to read from the pressure sensor. You can place only the sensor inside the inflated portion and have the rest outside, or you can use a [full module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N47LZ4P) that is placed inside the chamber.

You will also need an [air pump](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sparkfun-electronics/ROB-10398/1568-1344-ND/5684377) to inflate, and a [solenoid valve](https://smile.amazon.com/4inch-Normally-Closed-Electric-Solenoid/dp/B074Z5SDG3) to deflate. Both the pump and solenoid use 12V, so you will need a [set of relays](https://www.robotshop.com/en/4-channel-5v-relay-shield-module.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwssD0BRBIEiwA-JP5rJaHUD04ANRDE-ncjO4qd4qfJHGT3BT2Ik3MTv6_Ye1geRmE3RP2ZhoCTZwQAvD_BwE). Make sure that you have a way to restrict the airflow out, so that it deflates slow enough to get precise measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Government regulation of healthcare devices raises the entry cost to market for such devices, so it's no surprise none was found in my web search.

However, there's a non-Arduino [Bluetooth blood pressure cuff](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01718JVJE) which logs data to iOS and Android devices

You can also create your own following instructions [in this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MTEFFGE) with a capacitive pressure sensor and a [Mega 2560](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/mega-2560-r3).